# Dynamically-linked DLZ modules in BIND9

Tags: dns, bind, dynamic-dns

BIND9 allows you to link dynamically loadable zone (DLZ) modules at runtime using the `dlopen` driver. The unit test for this functionality passes for my environment, but when I try to run `named` with the compiled shared object file linked, I get this error:

```
dlz_dlopen failed to open library '/usr/lib/dlz_example.so' - /usr/lib/dlz_example.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

I already opened a ticket in the BIND9 GitLab [here](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/issues/1158), which includes detailed information about my specific problem.

More generally, I'm wondering if folks have any insight into common problems when trying to load shared objects, or experience using DLZ modules. My hunch is there is something I'm not understanding about how they work, and there's some silly misconfiguration that's causing the issue. Of course, debugging tips are also appreciated.

---

ISC Knowledge Base page "Using DLZ in BIND": https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00995

Comment: Have you checked `dmesg` – does your OS have maybe AppArmor rules requiring the modules to be in a specific location?

Comment: Wow, that is totally right! Tips on how to configure AppArmor to allow `named` to access shared objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're using either Debian or Ubuntu, which enable AppArmor by default and restrict which locations the `named` daemon may read from, or write to, or mmap, or execute. Any attempts to load modules from the "wrong" locations will be denied by the kernel and logged in `dmesg`.

The default policy is at `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` and only allows two locations:

- `/usr/lib/bind/*.so rm` – for most packaged modules
- `/{usr/,}lib/@{multiarch}/samba/bind9/*.so rm` – for Samba AD DC zones

Custom additions can be made in `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named` (as the #include statement at the bottom of the file indicates). That file doesn't have any begin/end delimiters, just the additional rules themselves such as:

```
/usr/local/lib/*.so rm,
```

To reload the profile after editing, use:

```
apparmor_parser --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you solved my problem. One thing that was tripping me up was that I had uninstalled BIND9 with apt and reinstalled from source, and for whatever reason the apparmor profile was removed from `etc/apparmor.d` but the change had not applied. A reload did the trick.